# Pyexcel doesn't manipulate the cells I tell it to

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I'm working with pyexcel to automatically open a excelsheet, manipulate some data in it and save it again.
However it only manipulates the first command and seems to ignore the others.

I access my file, with

```
book = pyexcel.get_book(file_name=file_to_be_manipulated)
```

whereas file_to_be_manipulated holds the link to the file

then I have my sheets in a tuple like

```
sheets = ('first_sheet', 'second_sheet', etc.)
```

and access them via

```
sheet_name = book[sheets[sheet_index]]
```

to iterate over the cells I want to manipulate I access the cells like

**HERE** everything works, I iterate over the second column aslong as there is something in it and 'delete' everything that is in the first two columns.
This works perfectly fine.

```
     row = 5
     column = 2
     column_to_be_deleted = 0
     second_column_to_be_deleted = 1
     sheet_name = book[sheets[sheet_index]]
     while sheet_name[row,column] != None:
         row_to_be_deleted = row     
         second_row_to_be_deleted = row   
         sheet_name[row_to_be_deleted, column_to_be_deleted] = ""
         sheet_name[second_row_to_be_deleted, second_column_to_be_deleted] = ""
         row += 1
```

**HOWEVER** here strangely I just want to manipulate *columns 2 and 3* from 'empty' to 'Default' and 'x'
but this doesn't work. The 'delete' in the first column works fine but the other two manipulations won't work and I can't figure out why.

```
    row = 5
    column = 1
    column_to_be_deleted = 0
    column_to_set_to_default = 2
    column_to_set_to_something = 3
    sheet_name = book[sheets[sheet_index]]
    while sheet_name[row,column] != None:
        row_to_be_deleted = row
        row_to_set_to_default = row
        row_to_set_to_something = row        
        sheet_name[row_to_be_deleted, column_to_be_deleted] = ""
        sheet_name[row_to_set_to_default, column_to_set_to_default] = "Default"
        sheet_name[row_to_set_to_something, column_to_set_to_something] = "x"
        row += 1
```

It just will work if some string already is inside the columns 2 and 3, then it works fine.

HOWEVER here I want to change the value of column 11 row 5 to '1' and just delete the first column like in the other examples. Here the deletion works fine as well but the '0' in column 11 row 5 won't change to '1'

```
    if sheet_index == 13: #ORGANISATIONS SHEET, L6 MUST BE SET TO 1
    row = 5
    column = 1
    column_to_be_deleted = 0
    column_to_set_to_one = 11
    row_to_set_to_one = 5
    sheet_name = book[sheets[sheet_index]]
    sheet_name[row_to_set_to_one, column_to_set_to_one] = "1"
    while sheet_name[row,column] != None:
        row_to_be_deleted = row        
        sheet_name[row_to_be_deleted, column_to_be_deleted] = ""
        row += 1
```

How comes this, it seems so random to me which command is executed and which not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with how pyexcel looks at Excel-Sheets.
Pyexcel first looks how big the sheet is with where the last data entry is.

Then it creates an array this big, and if you want to manipulate data outside this array it doesn't throw an error, but simply doesn't do what it was asked for.

So if you want to manipulate data in a column where no data is filled in yet you either have to create this column (how to do that see the readthedocs from pyexcel) or manually input some data in it first.